# Using maven as dependency management manager for MPS baseLanguage model?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, mps

Is it possible, instead of importing all runtime jars into MPS, to just consume external dependency management tool like maven and let it resolve and upload all needed libraries into MPS automagically?

Comment: A bit tired of adding runtime dependencies and figuring out that I messed up their versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Nope

Long answer: In theory you can use maven or gradle to fetch your dependencies and the transitive dependencies. For instance you can use the [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) task of maven to copy the artefacts to some locations. In gradle it's even [easier](https://github.com/IETS3/iets3.opensource/blob/master/build.gradle#L97). Then you select the folder in the runtime tab of your solution. At this point you will be disappointed because it did not add the folder but all jars in that folder as libs. There is no way to tell MPS to use all the jars from some location, it only references single jar files.

The only way I could think of how this theoretically could work is by using gradle and after fetching the dependencies also programatically change the .msd file. Sync the jars [in there](https://github.com/mbeddr/mbeddr.core/blob/master/code/plugins/sl-all/mps-apache-commons/solutions/org.apache.commons/org.apache.commons.msd#L7) with the jars that have been fetched. I'm not sure how to do this with maven though. But with groovy it shouldn't be that much of an issue.

If you choose to try the gradle way we would be really happy to see a pull request adding this feature to our [gradle plugin](https://github.com/mbeddr/mps-gradle-plugin). ;)

Comment: I have used maven-shade-plugin to build a fat jar. I have also excluded the project artifact to have the transitive dependencies and the artifact in 2 separate jars.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the [MPS Build Language](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD20171/Build+Language):

> Build Language is an extensible build automation DSL for defining builds in a declarative way. Generated into Ant, it leverages Ant execution power while keeping your sources clean and free from clutter and irrelevant details. Organized as a stack of MPS languages with ANT at the bottom, it allows each part of your build procedure to be expressed at a different abstraction level. Building a complex artifact (like an MPS plug-in) could be specified in just one line of code, if you follow the language conventions, but, at the same time, nothing prevents you from diving deeper and customize the details like file management or manifest properties.